# Problem with fontawesome , it doesnt appear

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

The font awesome icon doesn't show up?
Here is the code of `index.html` :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
      <h1>lol</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link to fontawesome is not working, try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
<h1>lol</h1>
</body>
</html>
```